# integration owl carousel + easyzoom

Tags: javascript, jquery, owl-carousel

I am trying to use owl2 carousel with easyzoom (http://i-like-robots.github.io/EasyZoom/)

In this page you can find the result http://www.youdev.net/example/owl-easyzoom.html

In the first example there is only easyzoom. On mouseover in the image, the coursor change, the zoom image is loaded and I can move on it. This is the result I want to get.

In the second one, there is the basic owl carousel code + easy zoom. On mouseover, the coursour change, the zoom image is loaded but I cannot move on the zoom image, it is always streched.

I think that owl carousel always force the dimension of the image, so there is no zoom effect. Does anybody know how to fix this problem?

Comment: If you don't read the tag descriptions, you're unlikely to get the right people looking at your questions.  This is not about OWL, the Web Ontology Language ([tag:owl]), but about Owl Carousel ([tag:owl-carousel]).  It usually helps if you add a language tag ([tag:javascript]) and sometimes a library tag ([tag:jquery]), too.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem, but I think I'm using another carousel.

I fixed by adding `width: auto;` for `.easyzoom img` and `.easyzoom.is-ready img` in `easyzoom.css`:

```
.easyzoom img {
    vertical-align: bottom;
    width: auto;
}

.easyzoom.is-ready img {
    cursor: crosshair;
    width: auto;
}
```

Best,
Eder

**EDIT**

Just checked your code, and solved like this:

```
.easyzoom img {
    display: block;
    width: auto !important;
}
```